# Using Chrome to debug React TypeScript .tsx file - Webpack

Tags: html, google-chrome, reactjs, typescript, webpack

I'm using webpack for bundling my js-files so normally I only see one big bundled file under sources in Chrome. However if I add a `debugger;` to my `.tsx` file I can see a single file just fine. My question is if I can get webpack to output all my files in Chrome Source so that I can browse them there and just click a row if I wan't the debugger to stop?

In the screenshot below I would like a folder for `Scripts/src` and then all my files.

[image]

Sample code:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <title>App</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app"></div>
<script src="/Scripts/dist/bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

index.tsx:

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import * as ReactRouter from "react-router";
import * as ReactBootstrap from "react-bootstrap";
import { Test } from "./components/test";

ReactDOM.render(
    <div>
        <Test text="Well!" />
        <Container />
    </div>,
    document.getElementById("app")
);
```

test.tsx:

```
import * as React from "react";

export interface ITestProps {
    text: string
}

export class Test extends React.Component<ITestProps, {}> {
    render() {
        debugger;
        return <div className="well">{this.props.text}</div>;
    }
}
```

webpack.config.json:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require("path");
var proxy = 'localhost:61299';

module.exports = {
    entry: [
        // activate HMR for React
        'react-hot-loader/patch',

        // the entry point of our app
        './Scripts/src/index.tsx',
    ],
    output: {
        filename: "./Scripts/dist/bundle.js",
    },

    // Enable sourcemaps for debugging webpack's output.
    devtool: "source-map",

    resolve: {
        // Add '.ts' and '.tsx' as resolvable extensions.
        extensions: [".webpack.js", ".web.js", ".ts", ".tsx", ".js"]
    },

    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: ['react-hot-loader/webpack', 'ts-loader'] }
        ]
    },

    plugins: [
        // enable HMR globally
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),         

        // prints more readable module names in the browser console on HMR updates
        new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
    ],

    devServer: {
        proxy: {
            '*': {
                target: 'http://' + proxy,
            }
        },
        port: 8080,
        host: '0.0.0.0',
        hot: true,
    },
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you already generate source maps with `webpack` (`devtool: "source-map"`) this should already work ;)

Instead of viewing sources in "localhost", use the `webpack://` item in the chrome debugger. This is the last item in your screenshot.

*If* the generation of the source maps works correctly you should have your source folder structure there. It may be contained in an folder called `.`.

For example:
[image]

I have to warn you though. Sometimes source maps don't work correctly and you break points end ups somewhere else :-x